# Substituir checbox para radio

Tags: php, html, mysql

tenho este código onde crio duas colunas de `type="checkbox"`:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Id[]" value="'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'"></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Id[]" value="'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'"></td>';
```

e depois faço este update à tabela da base de dados onde só atribuo este valor ao `input type="checbox"`:

```
$registro = $_POST['Id'];
$tratamento = $_POST['Tratamento'];
$imagem = $_POST['Imagem'];

foreach($registro as $value) { 
    $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoManutencao SET Estado1 = 'Pendente', Estado = 'Concluido', Tratamento = '$tratamento', Imagem = '$imagem' WHERE Id=" . $value); 
}
```

Mas quando coloco o visto na `checkbox` **Pendente** ele na tabela faz o `update` dessa coluna e também insere o **Concluído** e se fizer ao contrário acontece o mesmo e pretendo que só faça o **update** naquela que eu colocar o visto.

coloco uma imagem de exemplo onde seleciono o pendente mas na tabela ele insere o pendente e concluído e só devia inserir o que eu seleciono:

Comment: Na sua *query* você está informando para ele definir o Pendente e o Concluído nos campos Estado1 e Estado, respectivamente.

Comment: Na query do `update` estou. Na query da consulta tenho desta forma `SELECT centrodb.RegistoManutencao.Id,
       DataRegisto,
       Pedido,
       Outro,
       Descricao,
       Funcionario,
    Imagem,
    Tratamento,Estado1,
    Estado

FROM centrodb.RegistoManutencao LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.InfoLuvas

ON centrodb.InfoLuvas.Id = centrodb.RegistoManutencao.Colaborador

WHERE Estado IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse formato que você colocou os checkbox, o `$_POST['Id']` vem para o PHP como **Array**, para validar isso, coloque esse trecho de código para obter as váriáveis `$pendente`e `$concluido`.

```
$registro = $_POST['Id']; 

$arr = array_flip($registro); 
$pendente = isset($arr['Pendente']) ? 'Pendente' : null; 
$concluido = isset($arr['Concluido']) ? 'Concluido' : null;
```

Após isso, altere a linha da consulta:

```
 $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoManutencao SET Estado1 = '$pendente', Estado = '$concluido', Tratamento = '$tratamento', Imagem = '$imagem' WHERE Id=" . $value);
```

Assim quando o usuário não der check em alguma das opções, será gravado no banco de dados como `null`. 
Acho que isso resolve seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado....resolveu o meu problema